# Finding the closest point on the Line

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a Line $\overline{L}= t(1,-1,-1)$ and a point $P= (2,4,4)$.

And i have the question below:

Also determine the point on L that is closest to P

How can this point?

Comment: It would improve your Question to put the problem into the context where you encountered it.  The nearest point on L is the *projection* of P onto the line generated by (1,-1,-1).  It's unclear what that might mean in terms of math you know, but you should do substantial research before posting a Question, trying to tie an assigned exercise into the material it was intended to reinforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for a point $Q$ in the line in which the angle between $\overline{PQ}$ and $\overline{L}$ is equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}$

[image]

...which is equivalent to search for a vector $\vec{PQ}$ so that the dot product $\vec{PQ} \cdot \vec{L} = 0$

You already know that $\vec{L} = (1, -1, -1)$ and $P = (2, 4, 4)$ so you need $Q$.

Let's formulate the dot product:

$$(1, -1, -1) \cdot (Q_x-2, Q_y-4, Q_z-4) = 0 $$
$$Q_x-2 - Q_y+4 - Q_z+4 = 0$$
$$Q_x - Q_y - Q_z = -6$$

---

You know that the parametric form of $L$ given by $\vec{L}$ is:
$$x=t$$
$$y=-t$$
$$z=-t$$

Since $Q= (Q_x, Q_y, Q_z)$ is a point of the line, you can write $Q$ in function of $t$:

$$t +t +t = -6$$
$$t = -2$$

Now we have $t$ just replace it in the parametric equations and get the point $Q$

$$Q = (-2, 2, 2)$$

---

**EDIT:** it's important to remark that the vector $\vec{L}$ represented in the parametric equations must be the same vector $\vec{L}$ that you use for the dot product formulation, or it would give you a wrong result.

Comment: Why 90 degrees or PI/4? Everything else i understand?

Comment: @john You can verify that any other point $Q'$ will have an angle smaller than 90° degrees and will form a right triangle $PQQ'$. Using the pythagoras theorem the conclusion is that when the point $Q = Q'$ the segment $\overline{PQ'}$ will have the shortest length.